# XML caching in Django

Tags: xml, django, caching, http-caching

I'd like to use indeed XML feed but I have some performance issues.
XML feed is basically a URL with parameters which returns an XML.

I open the url by `urllib.urlopen(URL)` and parse the response with `xml.dom.minidom.parse`. It gives me a DOM object than I get the related parts.

The problem is I have to open a connection for the same URL so many times, which returns exactly the same XML. I'd like to cache the resulting XML ones than before I open a new connection I want to check it if it's already in the memory.
Of course, I have to flush the cache by every hour or any other algorithm.

However, I am little confused how I can implement it in Django? Or do you have any other caching suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.cache import cache


myObject = cache.get("myObject")
if (myObject == None):
  myObject = getObject()
  cache.set("myObject", myObject, 60*60) # Will cache the object for 60*60 seconds.
```

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api